# Stripe down the middle of BLTouch mesh is somehow not level

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bltouch, bed

I'm fairly new to 3D printing, but I've had my Ender 3 V2 for some time and have made some upgrades to it, including a BLTouch module and some non-stock firmware that seemed to really help. Now, I can't print a thing and I can't figure out why in the world this would be happening. I am using Marlin-JyersUI v1.3.5. I have taken apart the gantry and rebuilt it to the same effect. Test prints fail on the first layers.

I would assume that there is possibly something wrong with the X-axis, as when I rotate my glass buildplate, the positioning of this ridge does not flip with it.

[image: Mesh Viewer]